# Add a column with a default value to an existing table in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, ddl

**Question**:
Is there a postgres query to add a new column to an existing table and to automatically populate that column for all rows of the table with a certain value, let's say `"A1"`, **just once**, as the column is created, so that I can still set the DEFAULT value of the column to another value, let's say `"B2"`?

Just to be clear, I am looking for something like this:

Given `my_table`:

```
name   |   work
------------------------
bob    |  fireman
carl   |  teacher
alice  |  policeman
```

my query

```
ALTER TABLE my_table 
ADD COLUMN description varchar(100) 
DEFAULT "B2"
COMMAND_I_D_WISH_TO_KNOW "A1";
```

changes `my_table` into

```
name   |   work       | description
-------------------------------------
bob    |  fireman     | "A1"
carl   |  teacher     | "A1"
alice  |  policeman   | "A1"
```

so that if afterwards I run the query

```
INSERT INTO my_table(name, work)
VALUES karen, developer;
```

`my_tables` becomes

```
name   |   work       | description
-------------------------------------
bob    |  fireman     | "A1"
carl   |  teacher     | "A1"
alice  |  policeman   | "A1"
karen  |  developer   | "B2"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Referencing the most recent [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-alter.html), this operation can be done using two statements.

1. Adds the column with the old default value

`ALTER TABLE my_table ADD COLUMN description varchar(100) DEFAULT 'A1';`

2. Modifies the column to use a different default value

`ALTER TABLE my_table ALTER COLUMN description SET DEFAULT 'B2'`

A full reproducible sample has been included below:

```
CREATE TABLE my_table (
  "name" VARCHAR(5),
  "work" VARCHAR(9)
);

INSERT INTO my_table
  ("name", "work")
VALUES
  ('bob', 'fireman'),
  ('carl', 'teacher'),
  ('alice', 'policeman');
```

---

**Query #1**

```
select * from my_table;
```

| name | work |
| --- | --- |
| bob | fireman |
| carl | teacher |
| alice | policeman |

---

**Query #2**

```
ALTER TABLE my_table 
ADD COLUMN description varchar(100) 
DEFAULT 'A1';
```

There are no results to be displayed.

---

**Query #3**

```
select * from my_table;
```

| name | work | description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| bob | fireman | A1 |
| carl | teacher | A1 |
| alice | policeman | A1 |

---

**Query #4**

```
ALTER TABLE my_table 
ALTER COLUMN description SET DEFAULT 'B2';
```

There are no results to be displayed.

---

**Query #5**

```
INSERT INTO my_table("name", "work")
VALUES ('karen', 'developer');
```

There are no results to be displayed.

---

**Query #6**

```
select * from my_table;
```

| name | work | description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| bob | fireman | A1 |
| carl | teacher | A1 |
| alice | policeman | A1 |
| karen | developer | B2 |

---

[View working demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/r3w2SkSN4UF8YzncSrrAuf/0)

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Thanks, I was asking if there were a way to run "update table by adding a new column and set its default to A1" and "update table by setting the new column default to B2" commands at once, with just one query.

Comment: @Tms91 You asked a good question. However, I'm not seeing such in the latest docs (at the time of this post). Maybe they will consider this for future versions, you could submit a request [here](https://postgresql.uservoice.com/forums/21853-general) or [engage them further](https://www.postgresql.org/support/).

Answer (score 8):

Yes, you can do that by using two actions in one ALTER.

```
ALTER TABLE my_table 
  ADD COLUMN description varchar(100) DEFAULT 'A1', 
  ALTER COLUMN description SET DEFAULT 'B2';
```

I have verified that `DROP DEFAULT` doesn't work in the same command as the column was added in, unlike `SET DEFAULT NULL`.  I don't think there is really a reason for it not to work, it just happens to do them in the wrong order for it to work, and no one has bothered to force it to do it in the right order.  (Perhaps because no one even tested that exact thing and so realizes it is broken)

You can always just do them in different `ALTER` commands.  If you are worried that someone might "see" the table in an in-between state, you can do both in a single transaction.  Then the lock is not released in between so no one can see it.  The real advantage of doing multiple actions in one command is that the table doesn't need to be rewritten multiple times.  But here, it doesn't need to get rewritten at all anyway.

Comment: Works for me, in multiple versions.  What version are you using?  Is their anything weird about the table (foreign, temp, partitioned, etc.)

Comment: You can see it working at https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2CFNtdkLbc324etcsSrNTq/0

Comment: my bad, it works, I'll remove my comments

Comment: I just don't understand why it does not work when I substitute line `ALTER COLUMN description SET DEFAULT 'B2';` with line `ALTER COLUMN description DROP DEFAULT;` . To remove the default, only `ALTER COLUMN description SET DEFAULT NULL`  seems to work.